# Additional Boxes - Criteria, Longevity, Manipulability

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sixth-generation

*This feature has existed for a while (I'm not sure since when exactly), but I'm mainly interested in the Gen VI implementation (hence the tag).*

Usually, at the start of a game, you have some number of Boxes available. In B/W, those were 8, in X/Y I think it was 15. Under certain conditions though, you receive additional Boxes that just appear at the end of your current Boxes list. Which brings me to Part 1 of my question:

> 1) What are the exact conditions for additional Boxes to appear and do you always get 8 additional Boxes? *(Using Pokemon Bank reveals that in X/Y, the maximum number of Boxes is 31, which I have experienced to be unlocked in 2 steps of 8 Boxes each.)*

Since I'm a person who really likes to order and organize stuff, my Boxes have names and are used to categorize my Pokemon. This results in some Boxes ending up empty for a while most of the time. So here's to

> 2) Do additional Boxes you receive stay forever or do they disappear if the conditions for them are no longer met?
>
> 3) If they disappear, is there a way (such as renaming or putting any Pokemon in the last Box) to make them stay no matter what, even if you released all your other Pokemon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) What are the exact conditions for additional Boxes to appear and do you always get 8 additional Boxes? *(Using Pokemon Bank reveals that in X/Y, the maximum number of Boxes is 31, which I have experienced to be unlocked in 2 steps of 8 Boxes each.)*

More boxes appear when you have at least one Pokemon in your current boxes. When all your current boxes have at least one Pokemon in them, 8 new boxes will appear the next time you log into your PC (you start with 7 boxes, then get up to 15 boxes, then up to 23 boxes and last to 31 boxes, the figures exclude the battle box).

> 2) Do additional Boxes you receive stay forever or do they disappear if the conditions for them are no longer met?
>
> 3) If they disappear, is there a way (such as renaming or putting any Pokemon in the last Box) to make them stay no matter what, even if you released all your other Pokemon?

No matter what you do, those boxes will never disappear, even if you move all the Pokemon you have to a single box and the remaining boxes are empty.

Comment: Oh, it was even just 7 at the start. Thank you :) do you happen to know if the figures are different in older generations?

Comment: @scenia Hmm, I don't have the figures in my head... I'd have to start a new game ^^; I could try that tomorrow (in about 9 hours for me) if you want.

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: @scenia It's the same mechanics in BW/BW2 except that the battle box is completely separate and you have less boxes. So you get 8, then 16, then 24 boxes. In HGSS, there is only 18 boxes at the start and you don't get more by filling the boxes (at least, not by putting 1 Pokemon in each and I don't think you can get more boxes either).

Answer (score 3):

As far as i am informed, you have to have at least one Pokemon in every Box for new ones to appear. I don't think that the new boxes vanish again, but if they would - placing a Pokemon inside should solve it then.